# Understanding subscribing to an Action<int>

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I need help understanding the following.

I declare an Action for when the variable Count changes:

```
public Action<int>? CountChanged { get; set; }
```

and then I subscribe to the action as follows:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    this.data.CountChanged += (newCount) => this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

I do not fully understand the line of code below:

```
this.data.CountChanged += (newCount) => this.StateHasChanged();
```

My best guess is that it means something like 'when Count changes pass the new value of count as a parameter to the delegate' in this case it is unused, it simply calls the StateHasChanged method.  If this is the case, What is the += for?

Comment: "What is the += for?" - adding the handler to any that already exist. (You might want to read my article at https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Events)

Comment: I was completely misinterpreting this as when the value increases, makes perfect sense now, thanks

Comment: Given that you're treating `CountChanged` as an event, you should really use the `event` keyword, rather than having a delegate as a property.  It will expose only the operations appropriate for an event, and no more, which looks to be desirable in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, an `Action` is a delegate.

There are many ways to add a method to a delegate.  As delegates are "multicast" they can hold more than one assigned method. The `+=` adds the method to the right to the delegate while the `-=` removes it.

Be careful using `=`.  It will assign the provided method to the delegate and overwrite all previous assignments.  `delegate = null;` clears the delegate.

The first one below is the most obvious, assigning an existing method.  All the others create anonymous methods that are assigned to the action.

```cs
    public Action<int>? CountChanged { get; set; }

    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.CountChanged += OnCounterChanged;
        this.CountChanged += (int value) => this.StateHasChanged();
        this.CountChanged += (value) => { this.StateHasChanged(); };
        this.CountChanged += value => this.StateHasChanged();
        this.CountChanged += _ => this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void OnCounterChanged(int value)
    {
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Comment: [Polite] We assign a method or a lambda expression to an Action<T> delegate by using the assigment symbole (=), but we subscribe to an event or add or remove an event handler, by using += and -= . Your code, which I believe should work, ignores this altogether. If you believe the OP wanted to create an event, then tell him to add the event key word as well, in which case += is the way to go. Otherwise, tell him to use = instead.
Note that the correct way to define an event in .Net is: event EventHandler<TEventArgs>

Comment: `Don't forget += _ => this.StateHasChanged(); , that signals that it is the intent not to use the parameter. ` Gosh, what parameter ?

Comment: Official documentation quote "A useful property of delegate objects is that multiple objects can be assigned to one delegate instance by using the + operator. The multicast delegate contains a list of the assigned delegates. When the multicast delegate is called, it invokes the delegates in the list, in order. Only delegates of the same type can be combined."    The OP question was "What is the += for?" in an Action.

Comment: @Enet - we can assign it with either.  See my updated answer to cover both situations.

Comment: My understanding is that an event is a wrapper around a semi-fixed format delegate `void event(object? sender, {EventArgs} e)` that only lets you add/remove delegates.  It prevents overriding and clearing operations

Comment: The citations from the docs speak of multicasting delegates, and the role of the + operator. The are not the answer directly or indirectly to the question: "What is the += for?" If anything, they demonstrate how to define an Action delegate and how to add a method to it: //Action<string> hiDel, byeDel, multiDel, multiMinusHiDel; // Create the delegate object hiDel that references the
        // method Hello.
        hiDel = Hello;

        // Create the delegate object byeDel that references the
        // method Goodbye.
        byeDel = Goodbye;

Comment: Do you see any `+=` in  `hiDel = Hello;` I don't see. Can you produce any example in the documents where an Action delegate is defined and a method or a labmda expression is added to it with `+=` When I see  `+=` I know that we speak of an event delegate, and this fact should have been conveyed to the asker. And even using `event Action<int>` is not a best practice as this is not how it is done in .Net framework. They always use EventHandler<TEventArgs> Delegate.  If you use `event Action<int>`, will it work ? Yes, it will. So will you use it?

Comment: And of course using `CountChanged += OnCounterChanged;` instead of `CountChanged = OnCounterChanged;` will still work. No one suggested otherwise. But then the delegates internally created defferently, and lead to such coding:  public Action<int>? CountChanged { get; set; } this.CountChanged += _ => this.StateHasChanged();  
Henk Holterman says that such usage signals that it is the intent not to use the parameter.